# Badge progress circle misalinged

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

[image]

The double circle is partly outside the box. Is this a bug? I am using Edge, Windows 10.

Comment: Repro'd (filler)

Comment: Reproduced; Firefox on Windows 11.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Oh I totally forgot Windows 11 came out. :P

Comment: already reported on [Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373043/381197)